# Filter dates and sum the result

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little problem with my time sheet summary section.
In my workbook I have two sheets, the first is a "form" (I don't use userform, just placed the boxes, lists, buttons etc to the sheet) where I can record the info and get back the data after some operations. The second holds the data. In column "B" I have dates and in column "D" numbers with headers.

What I'd like to do: summerize the numbers in col "D" after filtering col "B" according to values of two comboboxes on the first sheet and show me the number in a textbox. In the first cbox I can select the year and in the second the month. Both are numbers. The date format in the list is dd. mm. yyyy.
I've tried to find some code (loop or autofilter) and change it to my case but couldn't make it work. Is it possible to this with vba? I don't want to use pivot.
Thank you.

Here's a look of my "form":
[Layout of "form"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHbcB.jpg)

Comment: Please show the layout of "form" and the name of controls.

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you have a read of [ask] and [mcve] please.  Also a picture says a thousand words - would be so much easier to understand what you're after.  You can edit your question using the Edit button just below the tags.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome - I uploaded a picture for a better understanding. In the middle-bottom part you can see two comboboxes. Year (Combobox2) and month (Combobox3). The year comes from the data sheet, col "B" mentioned above, but I made a code that lists only the year, not the whole format. The month is simply populated with the .AddItem feature and the sum will be shown in Textbox7 (Grant sum) under the Time sheet button.